# Undefined namespace Capsule in Illuminate database

Tags: php, database, composer-php, phpstorm

I installed [Sentinel](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0) with Illuminate database via composer, but it throw "Undefined Namespace" error now.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
```

*Capsule* is underlined in red.

Comment: Try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE to start with.

Answer (score 0):

just close your IDE and open again